# Using position: fixed with float value

Tags: html, css, position

I'm making a scroll to top button and I want it to appear on the right side of the page in a fixed position (roughly 60% down the page). If i use relative or absolute, it simply scrolls up with the rest of the page. However when I use fixed position to fix this problem, the button shows up on the left side of the page. I've tried using left with a percentage, but unlike float, it slowly drifts away from the edge of the page as you adjust the width.

here is my code (sorry for the disorganization):

```
#upButton {
font-size: 15px;
text-align: center;
font-family: comic;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 50px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
display: block;
position: fixed;
color: #000000;
float: right; 
top: 60%;

}
```

Does anyone see something I could change to keep the button attached to the right side of the page?

Comment: Post your html or better a jsfiddle

Comment: Use `right` and ditch the float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your **CSS** to the following

```
#upButton {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: comic;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    color: #000000;

    right: 10px; /* or right: 10%; */

    top: 60%;
}
```

just remove `float` and add `right` instead

Hope this will help you ...